# inline display of list elements through external .js file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple html page using external script and external styling.
In it a menu list is displayed using  < li > element.

The problem in my page is that the list elements are displayed vertically in block fashion, though they were supposed to be displayed inline. 
I cannot find the error for correction, so here I'm attaching all the relevant codes. Please help me know the error if you find it. 
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>
WEB pAGE
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<div class="div1">
<h1 align="center">Hello</h1> 
</div>
<script  src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload = "myfunction()">
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="div3"><br></div>
<div class="mmm">abcde</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**myscript.js**

```
function myfunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mmm");
x[0].innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML = '<ul id="menu" align="center"><li id= "m1"><a href="abc.html"  id="tn" > Abc</a></li><br> <li id= "m1"> <a href="def.html"  id="tn">DEF</a></li><br><li id= "m1"><a href="ghi" id="tn" >GHI</a></li><br><li id= "m1"><a href="jkl.html"    id="tn"> JKL</a></li></ul> ';
}
```

**mystyle.css**

```
h1  {
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
     }
.div1   {
    position:fixed;
    height:110px;
    width:1350px;
    background-color:Teal;
    color:White;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
.mmm{   position:fixed;
    top:115px;
    left:419px;
    background-color:#69A005;
    color:White;
    height:50px;
    width:1000px;
}
.div3{  position:fixed;
    top:115px;
    background-color:#69A005;
    color:White;
    height:50px;
    width:430px;
    }
 ul#menu{   color:white;
    margin:5px;
    padding:0px;
                     }
li#m1   {
    display:inline;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    color:White;
    }
a#tn   {    display:inline;
            width:90px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 
 tag from the below Javascript function. 
 will always go to next-line even if display:inline is used.

```
function myfunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mmm");
x[0].innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML = '<ul id="menu" align="center"><li id= "m1"><a href="abc.html"  id="tn" > Abc</a></li><br> <li id= "m1"> <a href="def.html"  id="tn">DEF</a></li><br><li id= "m1"><a href="ghi" id="tn" >GHI</a></li><li id= "m1"><a href="jkl.html"    id="tn"> JKL</a></li></ul> ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the br tags from your JS added HTML. It's not only invalid HTML, it will solve the problem as they force a line-break even if `display:inline` is used.

Also, you can't re-use IDs. You're only allowed to use each ID once per page.

You added HTML (and adjusted CSS) should look more like this.

```css
 ul#menu {
     color:white;
     margin:5px;
     padding:0px;
 }
 ul#menu li {
     display:inline;
     margin:10px;
     padding:10px;
     color:White;
 }
 ul#menu li a {
     display:inline;
     width:90px;
    /* removed for clarity 
     background-color:#000000;
    */
     padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="menu" align="center">
    <li id="m1"><a href="abc.html" id="tn1"> Abc</a>

    </li>
    <li id="m2"> <a href="def.html" id="tn2">DEF</a>

    </li>
    <li id="m3"><a href="ghi" id="tn3">GHI</a>

    </li>
    <li id="m3"><a href="jkl.html" id="tn4"> JKL</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I have removed the break tags `br` and adjusted all the IDs which cannot be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3g7omgh/).

Change your CSS class:

```
.mmm{   
    position:fixed;
    top:115px;
    background-color:#69A005;
    color:White;
    height:50px;
    width:1000px;
}
```

And your JS code (remove `br` tags):

```
x[0].innerHTML = '<ul id="menu" align="center"><li id= "m1"><a href="abc.html"  id="tn" > Abc</a></li> <li id= "m1"> <a href="def.html"  id="tn">DEF</a></li><li id= "m1"><a href="ghi" id="tn" >GHI</a></li><li id= "m1"><a href="jkl.html"    id="tn"> JKL</a></li></ul> ';
```